# Laravel form not working after clicking on the submit button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have created a form but it does not work after clicking the submit button. What problem do I have?

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 mb-4">
   <div class="card border-primary">
      <div class="card-header border-primary bg-primary">Create E-Pin</div>
      <div class="card-body">
         <from class="form-group"  method="post" action="{{ route('frontend.epin.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
               <label >E-pin Amount</label>
               <input type="text" name='amount' class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
         </from>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use some advance IDE like `visual studio code` or `sublime` with plugins to format and detect the tags so that you can avoid this type of typos, I understand it happens without IDE.

Comment: This is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it not work because you made a typo

```
           <form class="form-group"  method="post" action="{{ route('frontend.epin.store') }}">
            @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <label >E-pin Amount</label>
            <input type="text" name='amount' class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          </form>
```

**It should be form not from**.

Comment: Yes bro i have mistake